# Silverlight control behaves different dependen on the host server

Tags: silverlight, iis

I've got a silverlight application running on both my local machine and a webserver.
My local machine has windows 7 pro with IIS 7.5 installed, site started from visual studio with local IIS server as target.
the webserver has windows server 2k8 R2 installed, also with IIS 7.5

When I open these silverlight applications in IE on my local machine the behaviour of several controls is slightly different.
For example, one of our textboxes has a default value and a check on a min and max value.

If a user types 200 in this textbox in the silverlight app loaded from the win 7 machine, nothing happens. (using http://[ipadress]/[sitename] not localhost)
If you'd do the same in the silverlight app loaded from win 2k8, the value is automaticly ajusted (just as expected)

What could be the reason for this difference in behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Silverlight application itself is binary files that are packaged up in a XAP container. That itself is server agnostic. 
However, what is rather common, is that you perhaps have an older XAP in your local web browser cache and that you could actually running an older version of your app. Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Unfortunately clearing the browsercache didn't work. Also tried resetting IIS, no luck.